# Show that $\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot n}\leq 2^{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> Show that $$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot n}\leq 2^{n}\qquad (n\in \mathbb{N}).$$

I want to show the last step, that is, the inductive step. Assume that this equation is true for some $n=k$. Note that
$$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot n}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{i} \right ].$$
For the case $n=k+1$ would be
$$\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{i} \right ]=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{i} \right ]\left [ 2-\frac{1}{k+1} \right ]\leq 2^{k}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{k+1} \right ]=2^{k+1}-\frac{2^{k}}{k+1}.$$
I have to show that the last term is $\leq 2^{k+1}$. But it's not possible to show that $2^{k}/(k+1)\geq 0$.

Comment: To your last line, $2^k$ is positive, $k+1$ is positive, so the ratio remains positive.

Comment: If you really feel that you have to prove that $2^k$ is positive, you can of course do that using induction as well. It definitely is not impossible.

Comment: @Macavity Yes I agree. But then it should have been $2^{k}/(k+1)\geq 1$. Hence $2^{k+1}-\frac{2^{k}}{k+1} \leq 2^{k+1} -1$. The last term is now $<2^{k+1}$, but it's not $\leq 2^{k+1}$. My goal is just to show that $\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{i} \right ]\leq 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: @Ajmal $a < b \implies a \le b$

Comment: @Macavity Oh. I totally forgot this part. Thanks!

Comment: AjmalW: You seem to think that $a < b$ is a weaker statement than $a \le b$. Why? It is stronger, in that $a < b$ implies that $a \le b$, but $a \le b$ does *not* imply that $a < b$ (it might be true that $a = b$).

Comment: i don 't see what problem you have with your proof then? where's the complication?

Answer (score 9):

Another approach: 
$$\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot n}< \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot 2n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot n}=\frac{2^n n!}{n!}=2^n$$

Answer (score 5):

For the step from $n=k$ to $n=k+1$, we multiply by $\frac{2k+1}{k+1}$, which is less than $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $2r-1<2r$ $$\implies\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac{2r-1}{2r}<1$$

$$\implies\prod_{r=1}^n(2r-1)<\prod_{r=1}^n(2r)=2^n\prod_{r=1}^nr$$